# How to create a login that ONLY has access to run stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a `C# Winform` application that interacts with an `SQL Server` DB via stored procedures. In SSMS, how do I create a login that ONLY has permissions to run stored procedures? That login wouldn't be able to view/edit/create table definitions, etc. It would also only have access to a single specified DB.

The reason I want to create such a login is because I store the SQL Server credentials used by my Winform application in its `App.config` file. Since the app.config can easily be read, anyone with malicious intent can easily perform unwanted operations on the database if the given login had any other permissions than just stored procedures.

Comment: You can try encrypting the connection string in the App.config

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A neat trick in this scenario is to create a separate (custom) SQL Server role that can only execute stored procedures:

```
CREATE ROLE db_executor;
GRANT EXECUTE TO db_executor;
```

This role now has the permission to execute *any* stored procedure in the database in which it's been created - and in addition: that permission will also extend to any *future* stored procedures you might create later on in this database.

Now create a user in your database and give it *only* this database role - this user will only be able to execute stored procedures - any and all of them in your database.

If you user should be allowed to execute any and all stored procedures - this is a very convenient way to allow this (and you don't have to constantly update the permissions when new stored procedures are created).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I tried this and I can verify that this restricts the user and can only run the stored procedure which is what I need. I also like how I don't have to grant for each additional stored procedure :)

Answer (score 2):

Try folloiwng approach (`grant execute` should be repeated for every SP). Note that `MyStoredProcedure` has to be in `MyDatabase` :)

```
-- create login to server
create login test_user with password = 'test';
-- create user mapped to a database
use MyDatabase
go
create user test_user for login test_user;
-- grant permission to execute SP
grant execute on MyStoredProcedure to test_user
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query in order to allow stored procedure execute permision to your user

```
USE [DB]
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.procname TO username;
```

However, in my humble opinion , you should secure the connection string in the **app.config**.
Maybe , this [How to store login details securely in the application config file](https://nimblegecko.com/how-to-store-login-details-securely-in-application-config-file/) link can be helped to you.

Comment: I appreciate the link. I'll try securing the connection string as well, in addition to creating a restricted login.

Answer (score 1):

The access to a specific database is done through creating a user on the database that you want him to operate on. You can find more infos about users [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-database-user?view=sql-server-2017).

If the user is created you can `Grant`, `With Grant` and `Deny` actions for *every single item on the database*. 
The user will then be granted/denied those rights by a *grantor*, which is the `dbo` by default.
[image: userManagement in SSMS]

You can use this to also deny him access to every item on your database that isn't your stored procedure, which is what you're looking for if I understand you correctly.